# Mysql Inner join performance

Tags: mysql, performance, join

I have performance problem! I searched for Inner Join, tried optimize table but still the same. I have Users, Entries, Tags and tag_user tables.

This code works perfectly :

```
select * from `entries` 
where (
    select count(*) from `users` where `entries`.`profile_id` = `users`.`id`
) >= 1 
order by `id` desc
```

And I should add this to complete my query :

```
select count(*) from `tags` 
inner join `tag_user` on `tags`.`id` = `tag_user`.`tag_id` 
where `tag_user`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `tags`.`id` in (?,?)) = 2
```

It becomes like this :

```
select * from `entries` 
where (
   select count(*) from `users` 
   where `entries`.`profile_id` = `users`.`id` and (
        select count(*) from `tags` 
        inner join `tag_user` on `tags`.`id` = `tag_user`.`tag_id` 
        where `tag_user`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `tags`.`id` in (119,36)) = 2
    ) >= 1 
order by `id` desc
```

Any solution for better performance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first query will be faster this way:

```
select * from `entries` 
    where EXISTS (
        select * from `users` where `entries`.`profile_id` = `users`.`id`
                 ) 
order by `id` desc
```

It needs an index (`PRIMARY KEY`?) on users.id.  It is faster because the subquery quits when finds *one* row, rather than counting all of them.

The query part cannot use that technique.  But I think it is much simpler than what you have:

```
SELECT  e.*
    FROM  
      ( SELECT  user_id
            FROM  `tag_user`
            WHERE  tag_id IN (119, 36)
            GROUP BY  user_id
            HAVING  count(*) = 2 
      ) x
    JOIN  entries AS e  ON e.profile_id = x.user_id
```

Notice that `users` does not seem to be of any use.

`entries` will need `INDEX(profile_id)`.

I assume `tag_user` is a many-to-many mapping table?  Have you followed all the advice in [*this*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)?  The advice there may provide further performance boost.

If you need to discuss this further, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.